# Java Function/GUI

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a calculator with GUI, and I figured out I will have to repeat the JButton code million of times, so I decided to make a function instead, but I'm not able to do a function. Here's what I did

```
public static void button(String name, int size1, int size2, int loc1, int loc2) {
    JButton l=new JButton(name);
    l.setSize(size1, size2);
    l.setLocation(loc1, loc2);
    }
```

And inside the main, I did this

```
myForm.add(button("5", 20, 20, 20, 20));
```

After declaring myForm for sure, but I keep getting this error:
The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (void)

I'm new to functions and java, thus it looks confusing.
Thank you.

Comment: "*I will have to repeat the JButton code million of times*" - that seems completely wrong. Why would you want to add a million JButtons for a calculator?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Atleast 10-20 times, it would be easier with a function, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue 1

First things first, regarding your error:

> The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Your `button()` method returns a void, you have to make it return the object:

```
public static JButton button(String name, int size1, int size2, int loc1, int loc2) {
  JButton l=new JButton(name);
  l.setSize(size1, size2);
  l.setLocation(loc1, loc2);
  return l;
}
```

myForm.add() expects a Component to be passed, so you simply needed to return the JButton created by your helper `button()` method.

#### Issue 2

The second issue here will be with your application's design: there is no way creating 1,000,000 JButton instances makes sense.

It will:

- eat away your memory,
- be useless in terms of UI/UX.

More likely, you want to create as many JButtons as you need at any given time on the screen, and reuse these depending on the actions you want.

Considering your requirement, I suspect you want to try to display a very large grid of objects you can interact with (say a giant Minesweeper, Game of Life, or biology simulation maybe?). If that's the case, quite likely you'll want to draw the objects yourself and to handle events yourself to reduce the overhead.

Comment: I am quite sure that the OP meant *million* figuratively.

Comment: @meskobalazs: never know. OP asks, I answer. :) I've seen actual use cases or original designs of this kind, especially in lab environments, where scientists actually wanted something like this. Not necessarily with buttons obviously, but something interactive, and as they try to transpose to a UI they jump to the most "natural" element. Wouldn't necessarily surprise me as I've seen it time and again. Also common: homework assignment where the req is unfeasible and requires you to find the way to work around it with patterns (e.g. flyweight) and redraws.

Comment: @meskobalazs maybe OP also meant that the action of creating objects will repeat millions of times, not that a million of objects are needed at the same time. Don't know. More likely, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really mean million as a million, just doing a simple calculator :). Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the `JButton`:

```
public static JButton button(String name, int size1, int size2, int loc1, int loc2) {
    JButton button = new JButton(name);
    button.setSize(size1, size2);
    button.setLocation(loc1, loc2);
    return button;
}
```

I would also recomment a more clear name for the method, e.g. `createButton`.

Comment: `createButton` is arguably not this great. It will depend on the rest of the OP's API. `myForm.add(button())` reads pretty explicitly, and it's not uncommon to drop verbs in builder patterns. Not saying there are not cases where I'd agree with you, but building GUIs is already quite verbose in Swing, so sometimes avoiding the cruft is not so bad here.

Comment: @haylem Fair enough :)